# Type aliasing type constraints in generics

Tags: scala, generics

I have a situation where I want to use a bounded generic type as a constraint on what class can be produced.  The problem is that I need to

```
abstract class SomeAbstractClass

trait Foo[A <: SomeAbstractClass]

trait Bar[A] extends Foo[A]    
//  Fails error: type arguments [A] do not conform to trait Foo's type parameter bounds [A <: SomeAbstractClass]

// Need to write it like this, for every single subclass of Foo
trait Bar[A <: SomeAbstractClass] extends Foo[A]
```

Is there an easier way to promote that through the system without having to retype the bounds every time?

Answer (score 1):

Constraints on type parameters are constraints. They don't propagate transitively via inheritance as you would like them to.

Comment: Could you suggest a method which would result in the same effect?

Comment: If there's a way, I can't think of it. The introduction of a type parameter without bounds is completely unconstrained and there's no way to make that compatible with a bounded type parameter on another parameterized type without expressly stating a compatible type bound on the new type parameter (i.e., one that is at least as restrictive).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is applicable or produces some new ideas at least:

```
abstract class SomeAbstractClass
trait Foo { // propagated by abstract type member
  type A <: SomeAbstractClass
}
trait Bar extends Foo // no generic type parameter needed here
trait BAR[SAC <: SomeAbstractClass] extends Bar { type A = SAC } // introduce type parameter
trait Baz[SAC <: SomeAbstractClass] extends BAR[SAC] // generic type parameter needed here
```